# Can I bind F4 to 'emacs -nw' in mc?

Tags: emacs, midnight-commander

It seems it' ok to use 'EDITOR=emacs',it open GUI emacs. If I use 'EDITOR=emacs -nw', it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many programs that launch an editor based on the `EDITOR` environment variable. Unfortunately, they disagree on whether that variable should contain a shell script snippet (so that you can pass options to the editor), or should contain the name of an executable file (which may happen to contain spaces).

The safe option is to write a short script that calls your editor with the options you want and give it a name that doesn't include any special characters. Here's a sample script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec emacs -nw "$@"
```

Call that script `/home/chenge/bin/EDITOR` (for example) and set `EDITOR=/home/chenge/bin/EDITOR`.

Also set `VISUAL` to the same value (the two variables have the same purpose; most but not all programs understand both).

By the way, if you have Emacs 23, you may want to set up the Emacs daemon and call `emacsclient` instead of `emacs`.

Comment: Thanks,it works. I used emacsclient, but it has some problem while display Chinese chars in utf-8.